# Invert scale function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is interesting to me. Look at the following D3 code:

```
var scale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([100, 500])
    .range([10, 350]);

scale(100);  //Returns 10
scale(300);  //Returns 180
scale(500);  //Returns 350
```

Is there a function that inverse of scale? For example,

```
inverseScale(10);   //Returns 100
inverseScale(180);  //Returns 300
inverseScale(350);  //Returns 500
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Yes, there is, and it's aptly named `invert`.

```
console.log(scale.invert(10));   //Returns 100
console.log(scale.invert(180));  //Returns 300
console.log(scale.invert(350));  //Returns 500
```

Comment: Thanks for that - this comes very handy!