# Get x,y location of D3 point on path

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the below d3 chart and I need to find the x,y coordinates of the 7 points. I have tried a bunch of ways but can't seem to figure it out. I'm going to use the coordinates to create other elements that I need to put on the chart. `d3.selectAll("path")` gives me the array of the points I need but I'm not sure how to take those to get the coordinates.

http://jsbin.com/loluwirepi/1/edit?html,output

[image: Chart]

Comment: May be this be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172311/d3-invert-scale-function

Comment: What points are you talking about? If points are represented by circles, I count just six of them... Unfortunately, your JSBin is not even executable! For placing circles on a path you might want to have a look into [*"How do I return y coordinate of a path in d3.js?"*](/q/12431595).

Answer (score 3):

D3 scales convert a domain input into a range output. They can also do the reverse. The domain is your business content (price,time,total sales, etc.), and the range is the dimensions of the svg element.  Say your 2 scales are called `xScale` and `yScale`. If you want to find the x,y point of 97,000 and 25%, find the invert of 25% in the `xScale`, and the invert of 97,000 in the `yScale`.

```
var xPoint = xScale.invert(0.25)
var yPoint = yScale.invert(97000)
```